# How to use variable for URL inside cURL GET command

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl

I'm trying to get a specific json field from a cURL GET command in a bash script from an Elasticsearch index. To to this I have set up a script to pass variables into the cURL command. Hard coding the values gives the proper response so I just need to figure out how to use variables so I can get different responses for different purposes.

This is the desired outcome and the current working command:

```
docs=`curl -k -u admin:hunter1 -HContent-Type:application/json -X GET 'https://10.10.15.15:9200/logstash-linux-pci-2019.03.15/_stats' | jq '._all.primaries.docs.count'`
echo "The document count is "$docs
```

> The document count is 183,283,999

I am importing line-by-line indexes from a text file that might look something like this:

*list.txt*

```
logstash-linux-pci-2019.03.15
logstash-linux-pci-2019.03.16
logstash-linux-pci-2019.03.17
logstash-linux-pci-2019.03.18
```

I need to place an ip variable along with these^ into a curl command as such:

*reindex.sh*

```
user='admin'
pass='hunter1'
ip='https://10.10.15.15:9200'
indexList=(`cat "list.txt"`)

for index in "${indexList[@]}"
do
    echo "Reindexing: "$index
    docs=`curl -k -u $user:$pass -HContent-Type:application/json -X GET '$ip/$index/_stats' | jq '._all.primaries.docs.count'`
    echo "index "$index" has a doc count of "$docs
done
echo "Complete!"
```

The only thing that doesn't work in the above example is `....GET '$ip/$index/_stats'....`

I have tried hard coding the variables as plain text in the command like a normal curl GET and it works fine, I can get the doc count for the hard coded index.

I have tried:

```
....GET '$ip/$index/_stats'....
```

> Throws error: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

.

```
....GET "${ip}/${index}/_stats"....
```

> Throws error: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

.

```
....GET 'http://10.10.15.15/'"$index"'/_stats'....
```

> Throws error: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

.

```
....GET '$ip/$index/_stats'....
```

> Throws error: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

.

```
url="${ip}/${index}/_stats"
....GET $url ....
```

> Throws error: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

.

I have searched online for hours but anything I find is related to curl PUT and putting variables as json onto servers. How can I curl with a variable URL and index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: For anyone who finds this in the future.  The actual cause of the issue was using `http` instead of `https`.

You are using the quotes all wrong.

Variables inside `'...'` are not going to expand.  However, they will expand just about anywhere else like within double quotes.  For example this line:

```
echo "index "$index" has a doc count of "$docs
```

Here, the second double quote is terminating the first one.  These cannot be nested. You could just write this as:

```
echo "index $index has a doc count of $docs"
```

So that means your variables are not going to expand in here:

```
....GET '$ip/$index/_stats'....
```

This is equivalent to actually sending the literal string `$ip/$index/_stats`.  You want to use double quotes here: `....GET "$ip/$index/_stats"....`.

Another thing to watch out for is quoting the result of your variable assignment.  If for whatever reason the result of this command:

```
curl -k -u $user:$pass -HContent-Type:application/json -X GET '$ip/$index/_stats' | jq '._all.primaries.docs.count'
```

was `foo bar`, then the variable assignment turns into `docs=foo bar`.  This is the same as saying set a variable `docs=foo` and execute a program `bar`.  So you should be quoting the entire assignment.  However, take a look at it with a quoted assignment:

```
docs="`curl -k -u $user:$pass -HContent-Type:application/json -X GET "$ip/$index/_stats" | jq '._all.primaries.docs.count'`"
```

This is starting to look pretty ugly and confusing.  This is one reason why it is recommended to use the syntax `$(...)` over the backticks.  They are functionally equivalent, but it is easier to read what is going on here:

```
docs="$(curl -k -u $user:$pass -HContent-Type:application/json -X GET "$ip/$index/_stats" | jq '._all.primaries.docs.count')"
```

So, I went on a little tangent, but that is important stuff.  In all reality, this solution that you tried should have worked: `....GET "${ip}/${index}/_stats"....`.  I think your problem may actually be more related to the fact that it is in a script since it worked fine outside of it.  I don't see a shebang line and you may not even be running bash.  You are using some features (like the array) that are specific to bash.  Try adding `#!/bin/bash` to the top of the script.  If this doesn't work, try running your script like this: `bash -x reindex.sh`.  This is like a debug mode for bash, and it will show you the interpreted commands that are being executed.

Comment: I forgot to put the shebang in the post but it was in the program. My problem turned out to be that somewhere along the way of working on this I started using http instead of https. This causes `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Lesson learned, always check error codes before assuming it's another problem.